# AudioRecord read() returns strange values

Tags: android, audio-capture

I'm trying to read raw data from mic by following code:

```
            short buffer[] = new short[AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)];
            Log.d("O_o",""+buffer.length);
            AudioRecord rec = new AudioRecord(
                    MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 8000,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffer.length);

            rec.startRecording();
            int read = rec.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < read; i++) {
                Log.d("O_o",i+" "+buffer[i]);
            }
            rec.stop();
            rec.release();
```

But buffer always filled with 257 values.
What's wrong ?

**UDP:** look like i'ts initital values. Calling read() in cycle causes normal values.

Comment: are you testing on the emulator ?

Comment: Lol.. nice debug tag :)

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should take a look at [this question + answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151414/recording-with-audiorecord-on-android-speeds-up-the-audio). It shows some code which would improve your code very much.

Basically, your problem is that you're trying to read it synchronously. The Audio process will usually have to be implemented asynchronously and you'll be getting 256 byte-sized chunks of audio at any one time.